# how to share isolated scope with $scope of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem with my controller and directive. firstly i cant use the data after initialize directive out of directive (but inside controller).

for example i have a button that get some information, this information returned as city but i cant fill select element with city

cant access $scope of controller when i dont have a `controller:` in my directive.

cant pass model with `attrs.model` just two way binding work!

cant pass `$scope` of controller to directive (i declare a attribute in my directive `scope` that named **vm**) and use it.

some information: i have a reusable controller that have a `getAll` method that call `getAll` of my service that get data from database.

have a directive that use many time and initialize with `getAll`.

whats my wrong?

i need a service to get/manipulate data, controller to get/check data, directive to get/show data.

and {im beginner to angular, give me some keywords to search about them to help me how to achieve my goal}

excuse me for hard coding, i just test every thing to solve my problems.

this is my **html** code:

```
<div class="well well-lg" ng-controller="listController" ng-show="IsLoggedIn">

    <list-data type="" init="getAll('Person')"  model="person" data="FullName"></list-data><br />
    <list-data type="multiple" init="getAll('City')" model="city" data="Name"></list-data><br />

    <p ng-show="person.Id > 0"><strong>{{person.FullName}}</strong><il ng-show="city.length > 0"> is Citizen of <strong>{{ city | nameOfObject }}</strong>?</il></p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setRelation(person.Id,city)">Set Relation</button>
</div>

<div class="well well-lg" ng-controller="listController as myvm" ng-show="IsLoggedIn">

    <list-data init="getAll('Person')" model="person" data="FullName"></list-data>
    <list-data model="city" data="Name"></list-data>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getRelations(person.Id)">Get Relation</button><br />
    <p ng-show="person.Id > 0"><strong>{{person.FullName}}</strong><il ng-show="city.length > 0"> is Citizen of <strong>{{city | nameOfObject}}</strong>.</il></p>

</div>
```

this my **controller**:

```
    (function (app) {
    app.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$http','$q', 'listService','dal', function ($scope, $http, $q, listService,dal) {

        var vm = this;

        $scope.getAll = function (classname) {
            listService.getAll(classname)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.result = data;
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    console.log("Error 001: Can Not Load Data.",status);
                });
        }


        $scope.getRelations = function (pid) {
            var cities = [];
            listService.getRelations(pid)
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.citizenship = data;
                    var city;
                    for (var item in data) {
                        listService.getById('City', data[item].CId)
                            .success(function (data, status) {
                                city = data;
                                cities.push(city);
                            })
                            .error(function (data,status) {
                                console.log(data,status);
                            });
                    }
                    $scope.city = cities;
                    console.log($scope);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    console.log("Error 002: Can Not Load Data.", status);
                })
        }

        var addedCities = '', existCities = '', name = '', message = '';

        //Set relation between persons and cities
        $scope.setRelation = (function (pid, city) {
            if (city !== undefined && pid !== undefined) {
                if (city.length !== undefined && city.length > 0 && (pid != null || pid !== undefined)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
                        name = city[i].Name;
                        listService.setRelation(pid, city[i].Id)
                            .then(function (data, stsus) {
                                message = '';
                                if (status == 200) {
                                    addedCities += name + ', ';
                                }
                                else {
                                    existCities += name + ', ';
                                }
                                if (addedCities.length > 0) {
                                    message += addedCities + ' added succesfully.\n';
                                }
                                if (existCities.length > 0) {
                                    message += existCities + ' are exists.'
                                }
                            });
                    }

                    if (message.length > 0) {
                        window.alert(message);
                        addedCities = '';
                        existCities = '';
                        name = '';
                        message = '';
                    } else {
                        //
                    }

                }
                else {
                    window.alert("Please select at least one Person and one City");
                }
            }

        })


    }]);

}(angular.module('app')));
```

and my **directive** code:

```
    (function (app) {

    var template = function (element, attrs) {
        var htmltext =

            '<select ' + attrs.type +
            ' style="width:300px" ng-init="' + attrs.init +
            '" ng-model=model ng-options="value.' + attrs.data +
            ' for value in result"></select><br \>';

        return htmltext;
    };

    app.directive('listData', ['listService', function (dal) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'listController',   //if comment this line, directive will not work
            scope: {
                vm: '=',                    //if comment this line, directive will not work
                model: '='                  
            },
            template: template,
        }
    }]);
}(angular.module('app')));
```

Comment: you are approaching this completely wrong.  using `ng-init` for a select box at all isn't the recommended use for that directive, and passing the name of a function rather than the function itself isn't right either.  You should be initializing the data in the controller and passing the data only to the directive.  If you *must* pass an initialization function into the directive for some reason, pass the function (`&`) rather than just the name of the function (`=`).  However, don't do this, it makes the directive tightly coupled to the parent controller and defeats it's main purpose.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit "This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat"

Comment: so, how can i init my directive with difference data sources? i wanna pass a name of api to directive and directive (after load) fill with data of that api.
what about controller and directive scopes?

Comment: Ideally, a directive should be able to function on it's own if it were the only component on a page.  If the initialization code is the same in every instance, but the path is all that changes, then the initialization function should be embedded inside the controller of the directive and just the path can be passed.  If, however, the function is different every time, then it is *best* to get the data in the caller's controller and pass only the data.

Comment: if making the directive personally responsible for running the function is a requirement for some reason, then you must use the `&` notation in the `scope` of the directive to pass the function.  You ***still*** should run the function from the directive's controller, rather than `ng-init`, however, since `ng-init` is itself a directive, and may not have been processed at the time you expect the results to be available.

Comment: also, any functions that are passed into a directive need to be pure functions that return a value;  functions that modify `$scope` won't achieve the results you expect.

Comment: The best practice is to use services which fetch data, and don't try to do any initialization at the component (directive) level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to access isolate scope in your controller.
the thing is called `Two way data binding`.

if create directive there is many ways to define scope.

if you not define scope then default to set `scope: false` when scope set to false that means directive use it's parent scope and directive have not it's own scope only works with parent scope.

if you set `scope: true` then directive have it's own scope but also access parent scope.

and

if you define scope like `scope:{
name: '=', 
city: '@',
 address: '&'
}`

it's means directive create an isolate scope in isolate scope directive have it's own scope and doesn't access it's parent scope.
for communicate with controller/parent isolate scope have some prefixes that above we use `'=', '@', '&'` `'='` use for two way data binding t`'@'` use for initial value if you to get from parent or where directive called and the `'&'` use for accessing the methode or `callback`.
[more details](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/)

Comment: Its not my answer, plz read my question again. I dont want to share scope or makea child, i want to isolate scope and inject $SCOPE to directive and save data to $scope and then, after that use it for fill directive or use it in html.

Comment: I seen some examples in angularJS.org thatdont have controller defintion in directive, directive have a isolated scope and the example works very good.

Comment: you are accessing directive controller into parent view. you can call `getAll()` in directive template.